# mysql_affected_rows returns 0 but the database has changed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am experiencing a strange behavior with the function mysql_affected_rows that returns 0 even if a register in the database is changed.

I have reduced the problem to the simplest possible thing, so you can easily reproduce it.

In the one hand I have one file (page1.php) with the following code that simply updates a value in a register of the database:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbu', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('db'); 
$stmt="UPDATE aa SET a=4 WHERE id=0";
echo $stmt;
mysql_query($stmt);
$n = mysql_affected_rows();
echo "<br>N:".$n;
?>
```

In the other hand I have another page (page2.php) with this arbitrarily unrelated code:

```
<?php
echo "HELLO";
?>
```

If I go to the page1, the database is updated, N is 1, everything is ok.

If I change the UPDATE statement to SET a=5 and then reload the page, database updated, N is 1, fine.

But, if I change the UPDATE to SET a=6, then I go to page2, and then I return to page1, then again the database is correctly updated BUT in this case N is 0. Why is mysql_affected_rows returning 0 only in this case?

Answer (score 2):

mysql_affected_rows only works for the query that just ran in the executing script (If I recall correctly.)  Once you go to page 2, then reload page 1, no changes are being made, since they were made the first time around.

Comment: bingo, that was my thought as well.. unless OP is changing the values in the update query, it will show always zero affected rows after the first run

Comment: The query is in page 1, as well as the mysql_affected_rows, so the changes are made. Actually, the database is updated, but this function doesn't reflect that. Why?

Comment: @Víctor the rows "affected" are the rows changed, not the rows matched; though there is usually a connection setting to change that.

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes I know. That's why I am changing the update statement to set 'a' to different values each time

Comment: @Victor are you saying that N=0 on first run of page1, if loading page2 first?

Comment: @SilicaGel In the very first run, it works, N=1, ok. But in any next run, and only if page 2 is loaded first, then N=0 (yet the database is correctly updated)

Comment: @Victor if page2 is as simple as you say above, it should have no effect on page1.  I assume you're changing the value in page1 before loading page2, and then loading page1. (Can you see if the db is updated between loading page2 and page1?)  I honestly think page1 is being called more than once, as if it updates the db, it would have an affected row.

Comment: @SilicaGel Yes I am changing the update statement before loading page 2. After page 2 is loaded, the database remains unchanged (obvious). Then when I go to page 1, the database is correctly updated, but the value of N is 0. At first, I also thought that the problem was that page1 was called more than once. That's why I reduced the problem as much as I could, but the problem still persists! It's crazy

Comment: @Victor the only thing I can think of right now is that maybe theres an .htaccess file or something causing page1.php to load when running page2 or something.  Can you check for that, and failing that, check your apache or other web server logs, and see if any requests to page1 are happening without your knowledge.  I can't see any other reason for this happening as described.

Comment: You are right!! Page1 is loaded two times after page2:

Comment: But why?  I have emptied the htaccess file and still the same issue. What makes this page load twice?

Comment: I wish I could answer that for you.  Chances are its in your apache config files, or an htaccess file, or even an included file. (I assume your real files are a bit more complicated than the samples above.)

Comment: Actually, the real files are exactly just the code I posted. And the htaccess file is really empty... Page1 is called twice even if there is only one single line in the PHP code, this one: mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbu', 'pass'); If I remove this line, then the page is called only once. Any idea why this line causes the page to be loaded twice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120734/discussion-between-silicagel-and-victor).